# How to update cell value of my JTable?

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jdbc, prepared-statement

I'm finding a easiest way how can easily update my data in the cell using JTable. So far I'm trying to update my cell value of my JTable after selecting a existing record. What I do is to search a record of a **Section Name** after that I want to edit or update the values in my cell where my mouse is pointing. I see a lot of lessons in the Google but anything didn't give me a clear guide.
Screenshot below of my GUI.
[image]
[image]

**Codes for SELECT**

```
try (Connection myConn = DBUtil.connect();
            PreparedStatement myFirstPs = myConn.prepareStatement(searchSECTIONSETTINGS);)
           {
                 myFirstPs.setString(1, "%" +searchSection +"%");
            try (ResultSet myFirstRs = myFirstPs.executeQuery())
            {
                int resultCounter = 0;
                while (myFirstRs.next())
                {
                    String name = myFirstRs.getString(2);
                    sectionJTable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(myFirstRs));
                    resultCounter++;
                }//end of loop myFirstRs (ResultSet)

                if (resultCounter > 0)//If exist
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Found");
                }
                else//If not exist
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No Data Found");
            }//end of try myFirstRs (ResultSet)
       }//end of try myFirstPs (PreparedStatement)
```

**Codes for UPDATE**

```
String updateSECTIONSLIST = "UPDATE allsections_list SET SECTION_NAME = ? WHERE SECTION_ID = ?";

    try (Connection myConn = DBUtil.connect();
         PreparedStatement myUpdatePs = myConn.prepareStatement(updateSECTIONSLIST);)
         {
             for (int i = 0; i < sectionJTable.getRowCount(); i++)
             {
                 String sectionName = sectionJTable.getValueAt(i, 1).toString();
             }
             myUpdatePs.executeUpdate();
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Record Update Successfully");
         } 
        catch (SQLException ex)
        {
            DBUtil.processException(ex);
        }
```

How can I apply this method like this? Screenshot below. Any help would appeciated thanks!.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I think your question is not clear. Do you want to update more than one cell simultaneously?

Comment: @ReşitDönük yes that's it. I want to update more than one cell. Thanks.

Comment: Create you own TableModel by extending AbstractTableModel. So you can access each cell by getValueAt(int row, int col) and set each cells value by setValueAt(Object o  ,int row, int col).